# Docker Swarm Filters, Constraint and Scheduling Strategy

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am using Docker for Windows as well docker-ce on Ubuntu.

I have enable docker swarm mode.

- I came across many article that specify that swarm has different strategy like binpacking, spread and we can see that in docker info command but I am not able to see it.

  - Also some of the article specify about different filters like affinity, resource , port and constraint. I am only able to see constraint in docker service command but not other.
  - How can we achieve like this service only run on node that node is running service with some specific name ? ( There are many scenario but this is one of them)

Answer (score 0):

A few things to clear up:

1. Swarm Mode only has one placement strategy, spread. You might be reading old articles about the "classic swarm" before Docker released the built-in Swarm Mode in mid-2016, which did support binpacking.
2. There are many ways to control container placement in swarm, which I cover at length in [swarmmastery.com](http://swarmmastery.com) (paid course), and it includes (at least) placement constraints, placement preferences, global mode, and resource requirements. [See the docs on those features here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/services/#control-service-placement).
3. If you wanted to ensure two services were on the same node, the easiest way would be to place a "node label" on that node, and then create a placement constraint on the two services to match that label. This might be a bad idea if you want them both to fail over to a different node together if the first node fails. Swarm doesn't have a "pod" concept like Kubernetes so it doesn't have an easy way to guarantee two containers are always on a node together. For me, for things like php-fpm+nginx or codefusion+nginx I put them in a single image and use [docker's example of supervisord](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) to keep them together.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the "new" docker swarm mode does not have a built-in concept such as affinities. As a workaround, you can use labels, but as indicated, this in general has a problem with failover.

I had a similar issue, and created an "autolabel" program that detects a running service/task and sets a node label accordingly, keeping it updates as it starts/stops. You can then use the node labels and not lose failover capabilities.

See this docker repository: [davideshay/dockerautolabel](https://hub.docker.com/r/davideshay/dockerautolabel)

Source code available on github : https://github.com/davideshay/dockerautolabel

Looking for feedback to improve as well.